# How to widen the scope of a variable PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a query in WordPress and need to re-use the `$my_query_results` variable later on in my script.

```
function init() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    $my_query_results = new WP_Query( $args );
}
```

-

```
function process() {
    // I need to process $my_query_results here.
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'process' );
```

I don't want to re-run the query inside `process()`. How can I make `$my_query_results` available to the `process()` function?

**Background info:** The `process()` function handles data sent via an AJAX request. After processing, it sends a response to the browser. For example: `echo json_encode( $response )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If these functions are present in the same class you could assign it to a class property:

```
class Class
{
    public $my_query_results;

    function init(){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post'
        );
        $this->my_query_results = new WP_Query( $args );
    }
    function process() {
        // access $this->my_query_results
    }
}
```

Comment: Either move the process() function to the other class or instantiate the class where init() is present in the class where process() is present (not advised)

Comment: If the functions are both in different classes, it would be better to rerun the query indeed.
If this is the case, you might want to consider reviewing your code.

Comment: @Dr.Nefario re-running the query isn't something I want to do because if the query results change (i.e. someone created or deleted a post) then the results would be off from when the query was first run on init()

Comment: @henrywright In that case, use my solution and assign a property in the class :)

Comment: So you think my problem is best solved using an OOP approach?

Comment: OOP is always the best approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the variable as a param

```
function init(&$my_query_results) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    $my_query_results = new WP_Query( $args );
}

function process(&$my_query_results) {
    // I need to process $my_query_results here.
}
```

usage

```
init($my_query_results);
process($my_query_results);
```

Comment: or return it from init(). But due to the name of this function I doubt it is appropriate to either return it or pass it as parameter.

Answer (score -3):

or You can simply do global variable:

```
$my_query_results = null;
function init() {

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
$my_query_results = new WP_Query( $args );
```

}

Comment: Out of interest, why are globals bad practice?

Comment: There's one reason only: they are accessible by anyone at anytime no matter what, creating a ton of opportunities for hard to find bugs. Edsger Dijkstra's generation of programmers was plagued by goto statements, our generation is plagued by globals.